# Make Chrome load previous tabs on startup but keep them inactive or disabled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using Chrome version 119.0.6045.123.

I am chronically bad about having a lot of tabs open. I want them to be there when I restart Chrome -- but inactive or disabled (is that the right terminology?) so they don't use unnecessary resources until I actually *click on them*.

I have been in the habit of just closing Chrome and restarting when I want to free up resources. I'm pretty sure that has worked well in the past. But it no longer does.

Chrome is loading all tabs fully on startup, which takes a long time and wastes a lot of resources. Is there any way to prevent this?

=====

[Edit] The "this question has already been answered" link was mostly useless, as most of the answers are 5 - 8 years old, which in browser versions is ancient. But I was able to find a plugin that solves my problem. I posted my own answer to the linked question with more info. (The extension is called "Auto Tab Discard".)

Comment: Perhaps change settings to start fresh?   That is what I do. History brings back whatever I need. I am on the same version of Chrome as you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When you do that, does it reload and ACTIVATE (i.e. using resources) all your history tabs?

Comment: I just open from History what I need.

Comment: So the issue is you want tabs to come back up, but leave them in an inactive state until selected?

Comment: @Giacomo1968, yes, that's right. I want them to use minimal resources on startup until I actually select them. And then I want them to stay active (use resources) until I shutdown Chrome.